# If the squares of two integers are congruent $\bmod n$, the integers need not be

Tags: abstract-algebra, modular-arithmetic

How do you prove

> $a^2 ≡ b^2 \pmod{n}$ does not imply $a ≡ b \pmod{n}$

Answer (score 4):

By checking the simplest case:
$$
1^2\equiv2^2\pmod{3}
$$
but $1\not\equiv2\pmod{3}$.

It shouldn't be surprising, as $a^2=(-a)^2$.

Supplementary exercise: prove that

> “for all integers $a,b$, $a^2\equiv b^2\pmod{n}$ implies $a\equiv b\pmod{n}$” is equivalent to $n=2$.

Comment: But how do I put that in proof form?

Comment: @Kandace This *is* a proof.

Comment: You have to change the first sentence with the word proof, preferably followed by a colon.

Comment: but I have to prove that a^2 ≡ b^2(modn) DOES NOT imply a≡b(modn) with a formal proof. I might just not be understanding this.

Comment: @Kandace A formal proof that something does not imply something else is by exhibiting a counterexample.

Comment: Oh okay I was trying to do something else, that makes sense now.

Comment: $2^2\equiv 4^2\pmod{4}$ is another simple counterexample but not of the form $a^2=(-a)^2$

Comment: @Henry Nice example, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

$a^2\equiv (-a)^2$ and $a\not\equiv -a$ unless $a=\frac{n}{2}$